# getBytes() doesn't work for Cyrillic letters

Tags: java, pdf-generation, cyrillic

I found some answers but none of them works for me. I want to make a pdf file from a html, but the problem is that my html has Cyrilic letters and I found that there's something to do with this simple code:

> String s = "Здраво Kris";
>
> byte bytes[] = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
>
> String value = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
>
> // I tried with new String(bytes, "UTF-8") but it didn't work

Then I pass the value to my pdf generator function but it outputs only the part from the string `s` that is not in Cyrilic, i.e. `Kris`

```
 htp.CreatePDF("<html><head><title>kristijan</title></head><body><h1>" + value + "</h1></body></html>", "kris");
```

Comment: try this `byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: Did you try with the `String s`? `htp.CreatePDF("<html><head><title>kristijan</title></head><body><h1>" + s + "</h1></body></html>", "kris");` also `CreatePDF` looks like C# not Java.

Comment: I noticed I misplaced the brackets but doesn't work again

Comment: String objects in Java are always implicitly encoded in UTF-16. You can not change that encoding.

Comment: It's java and it doesn't work with passing just `s`

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: Did you expect that selecting a different encoding automatically translates `Kris` to Cyrillic? That is not how character encodings work.

Comment: Jesper, the problem is not converting `Kris` to Cyrillic, the problem is that before there's some text in Cyrillic that is not printed in the pdf. None of the Cyrillic text is displayed, that's the problem

Comment: I use this `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;` and it works fine with Latin alphabet

Comment: CreatePDF is not a method of PdfWriter. How is it coded?

Comment: *Then I pass the value to my pdf generator function* - have you considered the possibility that your PDF generator function cannot create Cyrillic glyphs? Maybe it creates a PDF using a font without Cyrillic glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at my answer to this question: [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf)

Several things can go wrong in your code.

This is a very bad idea:

```
String s = "Здраво Kris";
```

Suppose that you send your .java file including this code to somebody who saves it as ASCII, then your source code will change into this:

```
String s = "Ð—Ð´Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð¾ Kris";
```

I've also seen this happen when storing a document into a source control system.

**Bottom line:** never use special encodings when writing source code with hard-coded strings. Either store the strings in a file using the right encoding to write and read the string, or use the unicode notation if you insist on having hard-coded data in your source code.

Even if you store the file containing this string correctly, you have to be very careful when compiling the code. If the compiler uses a different encoding, `s` will be corrupted too.

You also have to make sure that you're reading the data correctly when converting the HTML to PDF. I assume that you are using XML Worker (and not the obsolete `HTMLWorker` class). There are different places where you can indicate which encoding to use.

Finally, you have to make sure that you use a font that supports Cyrillic characters. For instance: if you use the default font Helvetica, nothing will be rendered.

You can also find this information in the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around the inability (?) of createPDF to handle full unicode range of characters in Java (!) would be to investigate the

```
String s = "Здраво Kris";
```

for characters greater than 0x80. These must be replaced by the corresponding numeric HTML entity.

You can easily verify this by setting the String s to these entities and see what happens if this string is embedded.