# PoDoFo library c++ polish text to pdf

Tags: c++, pdf, chars, polish, podofo

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928112/podofo-c-pdf-library-polish-characters)
doesn't work for me.
Any other options?

**EDIT**

I have this:

```
string font = "resources//fonts//FreeSans.ttf";
PdfStreamedDocument document(output_pdf_name.c_str());
PdfPainter painter;
PdfPage* page;
page = document.CreatePage(PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(ePdfPageSize_A4));
painter.SetPage(page);
const PdfEncoding *pEncoding = PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalIdentityEncodingInstance();
PdfFont *f1 = document.CreateFont(font.c_str(), true, true, pEncoding);

PdfString eNtext("English text");
PdfString pLtext("Łódź stół");

painter.SetFont(f1);
painter.DrawText(100.0, page->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - 100.0, eNtext);
painter.DrawText(100.0, page->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - 150.0, pLtext);
painter.FinishPage();
document.Close();
```

and I see this in output pdf

[image: Image1]

If I set

```
string font = "resources//fonts//FreeSans.ttf";
PdfFont *f1 = document.CreateFont(font.c_str());
PdfString pLtext("\u0141\u00F3d\u017A st\u00F3\u0142");
```

I got

[image: Image3]

Hope, it will help to find the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf)

Comment: @TadeuszKopec I doubt that a question for one PDF library used with C# can really be considered a duplicate for a different PDF library used with C++, even if probably the cause underneath is similar. But as the OP hardly provides any information, it's difficult to say anything at all.

Comment: Fryderyk, if you really want help, please start by providing enough information about your issue. It is not even clear what your actual problem is, "doesn't work for me" might mean anything, probably each time you tried your CPU exploded...

Comment: Y, sorry. I edited question and added more info. Btw, its really annoying I need 10 rep points to add more then 2 urls... I wanted to show you more, but I cant :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
PdfStreamedDocument document(output_pdf_name.c_str());
PdfPainter painter;
PdfPage* page;
page = document.CreatePage(PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(ePdfPageSize_A4));
painter.SetPage(page);

PdfString eNtext("English text");
PdfString pLtext(L"Łódź stół");
PdfFont* pFont = document.CreateFont("TIMES NEW ROMAN", false, new PdfIdentityEncoding(0, 0xffff, true));


painter.SetFont(pFont);
painter.DrawText(100.0, page->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - 100.0, eNtext);
painter.DrawText(100.0, page->GetPageSize().GetHeight() - 150.0, pLtext);
painter.FinishPage();
document.Close();
```

This is the most important part:

```
PdfString pLtext(L"Łódź stół");
PdfFont* pFont = document.CreateFont("TIMES NEW ROMAN", false, new PdfIdentityEncoding(0, 0xffff, true));
```

Best regards!