# PoDoFo library and character with accent (ì, è, ...)

Tags: c++, podofo

As the title, when I create the pdf, accented characters are not shown or appear this **Ã¬**, how can I solve? I already tried with several encoding, but doesn't works.
Thanks  lot in advance

```
 PoDoFo::PdfFont* pFont = document->CreateFont("Liberation Serif", false, false, false, PoDoFo::PdfEncodingFactory::GlobalStandardEncodingInstance());


tablemodelint->SetFont(pFont);

if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Mon)
        giorno = "Lunedì";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Tue)
        giorno = "Martedì";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Wed)
        giorno = "Mercoledì";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Thu)
        giorno = "Giovedì";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Fri)
        giorno = "Venerdì";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Sat)
        giorno = "Sabato";
    else if(dataSel1.GetWeekDay() == wxDateTime::WeekDay::Sun)
        giorno = "Domenica";
        

    tablemodelint->SetText(1, 0, giorno + ", " + dataSel1.Format("%d-%m-%y").ToStdString());
```

Comment: Which encodings have you tried? Have you tried utf-8? What encoding is your cpp file saved with?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902838/podofo-library-c-polish-text-to-pdf) will help.

Comment: I tried all this http://podofo.sourceforge.net/doc/html/classPoDoFo_1_1PdfSimpleEncoding.html

Comment: n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I already saw but no

Comment: @luna80, which OS you are testing on? What locale you have it installed? I presume you are able to see those symbols in other applications...

Comment: @Igor, I'm on a linux computer (gentoo), locale is set to it_CH.utf8 and yes in other applications I see all correctly. thanks

Comment: None of the string literals in the code you gave us have any accented characters.

Comment: `Ã¬` in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is `C3 AC`, which is the UTF-8 byte sequence representing `ì`, so apparently you're setting the wrong input encoding

Comment: you created `pFont` but I don't see you use it anywhere. Please make a [mcve]

Comment: @Spencer, yes there are accents, for example Luned**ì**

Comment: @phuclv, I edited the code above

Comment: Try appending `u8` or `U` to each string literal. (I can't test this for you right now)