# Creating pdf files with iText and utf8 symbols

Tags: java, pdf, utf-8, itext

I’m testing creation of pdf files with itext library.
I’ve tried this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html
All works fine, but when I add some non latinic symbols (such as ā, ē, š), I get empty places instead of this symbols.
How can I resolve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: usually that means the font isn't available for the thing creating the PDF

Comment: Please read the [official tutorial](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) instead of third party stuff and you'll discover that your question is a duplicate of [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf)

Comment: Or if you prefer the answer to your question in French, I've translated it: http://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/133351-blowagie/b521/utilisation-polices-pdf-itext/ It's kind of frustrating when people ignore the official resources.