# Unicode unknown on jboss server

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, itext

I have a jsf project. So i put it on server (jboss). it exports (using ByteArrayOutputStream) pdf file using itextpdf. it's working fine on localhost. But Cyrillic font is unknown on server. I typed it following.

```
FontFactory.getFont("Arial", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 9,  Font.BOLD);
```

how to resolve this problem. please suggest me. I tested many way. it but still not working.

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but the reference to the answer is wrong. I have written this tutorial in French based on three StackOverflow answers that *do* address the actual problem: http://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/133351-blowagie/b521/utilisation-polices-pdf-itext/ The relevant answer on SO can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26631815

Comment: I tried it. But occurs error on server. error is not found file or resource on this path  /c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf/. in locally it working fine and knowing font. But on server it is not working.

Comment: I bet there's no C: drive on the server. Or if there is, I bet the application server doesn't have access to it. This is not an iText question. This is related to shipping resources with a web application. You could post a new question and rephrase it, asking: why do I have access to arial.ttf on my local machine, but not on my server? (Such a question would risk downvotes, though, because it's a very trivial problem.)