# Polish characters aren't shown when using Helvetica

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, fpdf

I make a PDF file from PHP.
I use FPDF library. I don't have polish letters in result PDF.
This is my code:

```
    $pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('helvetica','',TEMPLATEPATH.'/fonts/helvetica.php');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica','');
$text = 'WITAJ ŻÓŁĘDZIU';
$pdf->Write(5,$text);
```

I use this code (I tried to use iconv but it didn't work). My result is: 
"Witaj ¿ó³êdziu". What should I do?

Comment: The fact that you see `¿ó³ê` proves that you have an encoding problem. `ŻÓŁ` are characters in CP1250 encoding, whereas `¿ó³ê` are the representation of the same characters in another encoding.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/26631815/2564301 for technical reasons why this won't work "out of the box" (it probably won't offer a solution, but at least tell you why).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334134/fpdf-utf-8-encoding-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

Does your PHP script uses UTF-8 ?
FPDF does not natively handle UTF-8, that may explains why you get weird characters.

You can use TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org) which handles perfectly UTF-8.
The migration from FPDF to TCPDF is quite easy since it uses the same methods (same methods names, same arguments) as FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **UTF-8 encoding** **$text**?

Set your second last line of code to:

```
$text = utf8_encode('WITAJ ŻÓŁĘDZIU');
```